# What is the best way of using ByteBuffer to handle interleaved read/write in Java?

Tags: java, buffer, nio, nonblocking

### Edited: to make the question less 'opinion-based'

I want to ask for the suggestible way of using bytebuffer in the case of interleaved read/write.

My program processes a random sequence of NIO that performs `read()` and `write()` operation to a `ByteBuffer`. Currently I use a variable to record whether the last operation was `read()` or `write()`, and call `flip()` or `compact()` accordingly.

Is this the best approach or ByteBuffer is not meant to handle this task?

---

Original question title: Is Java ByteBuffer poorly designed?

I just started with Java NIO and I think the Bytebuffer is designed in a way that makes ***interleaved*** read/write operations difficult to achieve. Where such operation pattern is exactly the reason why we have a "buffer" in NIO.

Specifically, the `flip()` and `compact()` is unnecessary details for programming. If I have a random sequence of `read()` and `write()` to a bytebuffer, then I have not choice but to keep a separate variable to track whether the buffer has been 'flipped'. For example, for a flipped buffer I need to `compact()` it before `write` again, but I cannot do so for an unflipped buffer.

IMO, there is almost no case that a `write()` following `read()` do no need to call `compact()` or `clear()` first. Also, no `read()` after `write()` is without `flip()`, so I think either should be done:

- make 'read mode' and 'write mode' explicit and throw warning if write in read mode or vice versa. Use a explicit `readMode()` or `writeMode()` command to switch.
- remove the need to flip/compact before read/write by either adopt a different design (e.g. circular buffer) or by making it implicit in read/write.

As I am still quite new to Java, I want to know if my complaint is legit or there is some careful design choice going on in implementing Bytebuffer?

Comment: I agree with you, and they should have had separate read and write positions and limits, and they have indeed made circular buffering impossible, and the `flip()` operation is poorly named, and relationship of `ByteBuffer` to the other types of buffer isn't seamless, but this question is primarily opinion-based and will no doubt be closed pretty quickly.

Comment: The documentation of `flip()` and `compact()` rely on talking about the internal variables `limit` and `position`. In my opinion, it indicates that these methods are tied closely to the **implementation** of the ByteBuffer but not the **usage of a Buffer**, and in general it may not be good to expose methods that are only meaningful to the particular implementation.

Comment: You can't get away from the necessity for using them, so this is a distinction without a difference.

Comment: @Ruomu: The documentation of many `String` methods rely on talking about the internal variable `length`. In your opinion, does that indicate that those methods are tied closely to the **implementation** of the String but not the **usage of a CharSequence**, and in general it may not be good to expose methods that are only meaningful to the particular implementation?

Comment: @ruakh Thank you for the comment. I see, sometimes it is unavoidable to create method that is tied to a particular implementation. On the other hand, the example you gave is not perfectly convincing to me as `length` should be a property of any `String`. But I totally see that there is no consensus on what is considered as **internal**.

Comment: @user207421 Thank you. I am still new to Stackoverflow and I have edited the question so it is not so personal and opinion-based as before. Sorry I do not understand the part you mentioned 'a distinction without a difference', may I know which part are you referring to?

Comment: Where you say that `flip()/compact()` are about the implementation not the specification. It's (a) untrue, as it's specified, but also (b) a pointless distinction, as you have to call them, no escape from that.

Comment: But to answer your actual question as it now is, the way to handle interleaved reads and writes is to always maintain the buffer in the state ready for read, and always do flip/write/compact whenever you write, thus: `try { buffer.flip(); count = channel.write(buffer); } finally { buffer.compact(); }`, with suitable synchronization around both. That way you always know the prior and post state, and you always get the correct state for each operation whether read or write. I'm supporting a system written on this principle that has been running bug free for 15 years.

Comment: @user207421 Great! I think this way is indeed neat and it also handles threads well! Thank you. 15 years bug-free system is truly amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to user207421 for answering. He proposed a wonderful solution which I am adopting in my design now.

Basically, you always keep the `ByteBuffer` in the same state after each operation.

For example, to keep the `ByteBuffer` in unflipped state, then every `write()` operation should be wrapped with `flip()` and `compact()` before and after. Also, Add synchronization to deal with threads.

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of what I actually said. Nowhere did I say you can wrap a read operation with flip and compact, and if you try it it won't work. It is the *write* operation that has to be so wrapped, and that is what I said above. And the quotation from my comment is partial and distorts the meaning.

Comment: @user207421 I am sorry. I have fixed the read/write part and I have removed the quotes. I will read people's answer more carefully next time. Thank you.